# How to Bring button (which opens modal) on top of modal as well? React native

Tags: react-native, user-interface, modal-dialog

I am using `react-native-modal`. I am using modal's overlay, and the button which opens up modal, changes to cross button, but it stays behind the overlay of modal. I want that button to be on top of modal when modal is visible. I have already tried zIndex with the button but it didn't work. Need help with this. Thanks in advance.

Something like this but with modal overlay:
[image: tab bar popup]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Modal` component of react native traps the focus inside the modal content while visible. The only way to capture a click on the button is to display another copy of it inside the `Modal` component. If you manage to display it at the same position, the user won't see that it's another button.

Comment: you mean there is no solution to it?